# How to make the html text incorporated into xul copyable?

Tags: xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm opening the xul as new tab in Thunderbird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer in my particular case. I was using openTab with XUL containing HTML. Now I started to use openContentTab with local html file. So, the text is copyable now.